# ¿Cómo asignar diferentes colores a los puntos de un plot en R?

Tags: r, regresión-lineal, plotly

Estoy tratando de crear un gráfico de dispersión, me gustaría que los puntos del plot tengan colores según una de las variables de mi base de datos (continente). A continuación, la base de datos y código para que me puedan corregir. Quiero además, que no me aparezcan números en las etiquetas sino el nombre determinado por la variable (país). El objetivo es hacer la simulación y pues hasta ahí me resulta pero al anexar las dos líneas antes del plot, deja de funcionar.

De antemano, muchas gracias. ¡Saludos!

[image: Base de datos resumida]

[image: El código]

[image: Gráfico que obtengo]

[image: Quiero obtener un gráfico similar a este:]

Comment: Bienvenido YASC a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Por favor copia el código como texto no como imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo visto tu gráfico se ve negro por la superposición de los puntos, lo cuales me parece que tienen un contorno negro, y al haber tantos se ve así. Te recomendaría hacer ese gráfico con la libraría `ggplot2` ya que en cierto modo es más comoda de leer que el paquete de gráfico báse de R.

Si descartar usar ggplot, te recomendaría que cambies el `pch` por uno que no tenga contorno y también que ajustes la opacidad de gráfico.

Aquí un ejemplo con ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

temporal %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = pib_per_capita, y = esperanza_de_vida, color = continente)) +
 geom_point(alpha = 0.3)
```

Por otro lado, trata siempre de compartir código en formato de texto, no en una imagen. `Ctrl + C` y `Ctrl + V` es el mejor amigo de los que te quieren ayudar en stackoverflow

Comment: Muchas gracias, Johan Rosa.